# NgSwitch - How to disable other buttons by clicking on button

Tags: angular, typescript

I have written a small menu, which consists of three buttons. If you click on a button the respective component is opened. By clicking on Button the icon changes to x (used to hide the component). Now I would like if I click on a button the other two should be disabled and if I hide the button with icon x the buttons should be enabled again. Do you know how to do this?

My code:

```
// Template
  <div class="externalArea" [ngSwitch]="viewMode">
    <app-import (currentImport)="setCurrentImport($event)" *ngSwitchCase="'showImport'"></app-import>
    <app-export (currentExport)="setCurrentExport($event)" *ngSwitchCase="'showExport'"></app-export>
    <app-calculatory-bookings (currentCalculatoryBookings)="setCurrentCalculatoryBookings($event)" *ngSwitchCase="'showCalculatoryBookings'"></app-calculatory-bookings>
  </div>
```

```
<button type="button" [class.active]="viewMode=='showCalculatoryBookings'" (click)="toggleCalculatoryBookings()">
<i class="fas fa-calculator" *ngIf="!(show)" matTooltip="Kalkulatorische Buchungen"></i>
<i class="fas fa-times" (click)="cancelCalculatoryBookings()" *ngIf="show" matTooltip="Beenden"></i>
</button>
<button type="button" [class.active]="viewMode=='showImport'" (click)="toggleImport()">
<i class="fas fa-upload" *ngIf="!(show1)" matTooltip="SuSa importieren" ></i>
<i class="fas fa-times" (click)="cancelImport()" *ngIf="show1" matTooltip="Beenden"></i>
</button>
<button type="button" [class.active]="viewMode=='showExport'" (click)="toggleExport()">
<i class="fas fa-download" *ngIf="!(show2)" matTooltip="SuSa exportieren"></i>
<i class="fas fa-times" (click)="cancelExport()" *ngIf="show2" matTooltip="Beenden"></i>
</button>
```

```
// TS
toggleImport() {
    this.viewMode = 'showImport';
    this.show1 = !this.show1;
    this.isDisabled = true;
  }

  toggleExport() {
    this.viewMode = 'showExport';
    this.show2 = !this.show2;
    this.isDisabled = true;
  }

  toggleCalculatoryBookings() {
    this.viewMode = 'showCalculatoryBookings';
    this.show = !this.show;
    this.isDisabled = true;
  }

  cancelImport() {
    this.viewMode = '';
    this.show1 = false;
  }

  cancelExport() {
    this.viewMode = '';
    this.show2 = false;
  }

  cancelCalculatoryBookings() {
  this.viewMode = '';
  this.show = false;
}
```

Comment: can you please create a working `stackblitz` for this! I can help you on that so I see what we are trying to achieve

Comment: Here is my work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vgeggh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: is it only 3 buttons always or it will be inside an `ngFor`?

Comment: Yes it only for 3 Buttons